# Substring a string in JAVA

Tags: java, string

Is possible to substring this `String = "D:/test/for test/change.txt:D:/test/for test/further.txt:D:/test/for test/yandex.txt"` to:

```
D:/test/for test/change.txt

D:/test/for test/further.txt

D:/test/for test/yandex.txt
```

Because are two column, I can not `split()` use `":"`.

Comment: i think the best logic is replace `:D:` to `{SPACE}D:` and split by space eg.  `replace(":D:"," D:").split(" ");`

Comment: @DilermandoLima There is a space in the path itself as well. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regular expression below splits on ":" that are followed by a "driveletter:"

```
String s = "D:/test/for test/change.txt:D:/test/for test/further.txt:D:/test/for test/yandex.txt";
s.split(":(?=\\w:)");
==> String[3] { "D:/test/for test/change.txt"
              , "D:/test/for test/further.txt"
              , "D:/test/for test/yandex.txt" }
```

Note that this won't help if additional paths don't begin with `driveletter:`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want to split on a colon whenever it's not followed by a slash.  For that, the regular expression you need is a "negative lookahead", which means "not followed by".  So you should write `myString.split(":(?!/)")` - the `(?!  )` is how to write the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split it on `:(?=[A-Za-z]:\/)` which can be explained as

- `:` : The character `:`
- `(?=` : Start of lookahead

  - `[A-Za-z]` : An alphabet
  - `:\\/` : The character `:` followed by `/`
- `)` : End of lookahead

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "D:/test/for test/change.txt:D:/test/for test/further.txt:D:/test/for test/yandex.txt";
        String[] paths = str.split(":(?=[A-Za-z]:\\/)");
        Arrays.stream(paths).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
D:/test/for test/change.txt
D:/test/for test/further.txt
D:/test/for test/yandex.txt
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qOPzU8)