# Adding a suffix to a file name before file extension

Tags: java, properties, java.util.logging

I need to create an application that adds some suffix to some file name before the file extension.
The application takes one obligatory argument - the path to a config file.
I did a `config.properties` file whith `value/key:`

`mode=copy` (keep the source file)
`suffix=abc`
`files=change.txt:further.txt:yandex.txt` (a list of files for suffixing. File paths are separated with column:.)

For log a message I use `java.util.logging`.

- if mode from config is not recognized, log `Mode is not recognized: <mod_input_value>` at SEVERE level and stop the execution.
  Example: `Mode is not recognized: copi`
- if suffix is not set, log `No suffix is configured` at SEVERE level and stop the execution.
- if files are not specified, log `No files are configured to be copied/moved` at WARNING level and stop the execution.
- if one of the specified files does not exist, log `No such file: <file-path>` at SEVERE level, but do not stop the processing of other files. Note that a file path in the message must contain not backslashes but forward slashes ('/') to separate the path parts.
  Example: `No such file: src/test/resources/no-such-file.txt`
- When copying a file, log `<source-file> -> <destination-file>` at INFO level.
  Note, that file path in the message must contain  not backslashes but forward slashes (/) to separate path parts, not backslashes.
  Example: `src/test/resources/file.txt -> src/test/resources/file-suffix.txt`

I made the following code:

```
    public class Suffixing {
        public static String PATH_TO_PROPERTIES = "src/main/resources/config.properties";
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
            FileInputStream fileInputStream;
            Logger logging = Logger.getLogger(Suffixing.class.getName());
            Properties prop = new Properties();
    
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
            prop.load(fileInputStream);
            
            String mode = prop.getProperty("mode");
            String suffix = prop.getProperty("suffix");
            String files = prop.getProperty("files");

            File one = new File("D:/map/test/change.txt");
            File two = new File("D:/map/test/further.txt");
            File three = new File("D:/map/test/yandex.txt");
            for (String file : files.split(":")) {
    
                if (mode != "copy") {
                    logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "Mode is not recognized: " + mode);
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } else if (prop.getProperty(suffix) == "") {
                    logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No suffix is configured");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } else if (prop.getProperty("files") == "") {
                    logging.log(Level.WARNING, "No files are configured to be copied/moved");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } else if (!one.exists() || !two.exists() || !three.exists()) {
                    logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No such file: ");
                } else {
    
                    int at = file.indexOf('.');
                    String newFile = file.substring(0, at) + suffix + file.substring(at);
                    File dest = new File("D:/map/test" + newFile);
                    logging.log(Level.INFO, prop.getProperty("files") + "-->" + dest);
                }
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

For some inputs the code is working incorrectly, what do I need to modify?

Comment: `mode != "copy"` is not how you do `String` comparison, use `String#equals` instead

Comment: You shouldn't reference `src` with in your code.  If the files are contained within your application context, they are likely not going to be writable and can't be accessed as "files"

Comment: "For some inputs": such as what? "... the code is working incorrectly": such as how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop execution at first error, you would be better off by changing all the error logging like this:

```
logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "Mode is not recognized: " + mode);
```

to throw RuntimeException (or whatever suitable exception class you pick) such as:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Mode is not recognized: " + mode);
```

You should tidy your file handling, loading properties cleanly:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try(var in = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES)) {
    prop.load(in);
}
String mode = prop.getProperty("mode");
String suffix = prop.getProperty("suffix");
String files = prop.getProperty("files");
```

It does not make sense to do all those checks inside the loop because they won't be executed unless "files" is set, so pull these out of the for loop:

```
if (!Objects.equals(mode, "copy"))
    logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "Mode is not recognized: " + mode);
if (suffix == null || suffix.isBlank()) {
    logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No suffix is configured");
}
if (files == null || files.isBlank()) {
    logging.log(Level.WARNING, "No files are configured to be copied/moved");
}
```

Its not clear why you need one/two/three and this line if the files are read from config.properties:

```
if (!one.exists() || !two.exists() || !three.exists()) {
     logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No such file: ");
```

The loop over "files" should use `lastIndexOf()` in case there are dots in the directory names.

```
for (String file : files.split(":")) {
    File f = new File(file);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No such file: "+f);
    } else {
        int at = file.lastIndexOf('.');
        String newFile = file.substring(0, at) + "-" + suffix + file.substring(at);
        File dest = new File(newFile);
        logging.log(Level.INFO, f + "-->" + dest);
    }
}
```

The `split(":")` won't work for Windows paths with drive letters, but you have covered that issue in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456499/substring-a-string-in-java).

Comment: throw new RuntimeException("Mode is not recognized: " + mode);,  I need use log...

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare `String`s with `==`. You should always use `equals()` instead. Read more at [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Having said that, try the following:

```java
public class Suffixing {
    public static String PATH_TO_PROPERTIES = "src/main/resources/config.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        Logger logging = Logger.getLogger(Suffixing.class.getName());
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
        prop.load(fileInputStream);
        
        String mode = prop.getProperty("mode");
        String suffix = prop.getProperty("suffix");
        String files = prop.getProperty("files");

        File one = new File("D:/map/test/change.txt");
        File two = new File("D:/map/test/further.txt");
        File three = new File("D:/map/test/yandex.txt");
        for (String file : files.split(":")) {
            if (!Objects.equals(mode, "copy")) {
                logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "Mode is not recognized: " + mode);
                fileInputStream.close();
            } else if (prop.getProperty(suffix).isBlank()) {
                logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No suffix is configured");
                fileInputStream.close();
            } else if (prop.getProperty("files").isBlank()) {
                logging.log(Level.WARNING, "No files are configured to be copied/moved");
                fileInputStream.close();
            } else if (!one.exists() || !two.exists() || !three.exists()) {
                logging.log(Level.SEVERE, "No such file: ");
            } else {
                int at = file.indexOf('.');
                String newFile = file.substring(0, at) + suffix + file.substring(at);
                File dest = new File("D:/map/test" + newFile);
                logging.log(Level.INFO, prop.getProperty("files") + "-->" + dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Petru Ciorba does this help you? If not why? We need some feedback to be able to help you further.